# Altered kebab case Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using the following `toKebabCase()` function:

```js
function toKebabCase(key) {
  return key.match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
    .map((word) => word.toLowerCase())
    .join('-');
}

console.log(toKebabCase('namespaceGray100Light'));
```

It doesn't behave *exactly* as I would like, though. Right now, if I pass `'namespaceGray100Light'` as an argument, the function returns `'namespace-gray100-light'`. How would this regex need to be modified in order to return `'namespace-gray-100-light'`.

To clarify, I am looking to introduce a hyphen when a digit follows an alpha character and not just when a digit precedes an alpha character.

TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `[0-9]*` from the pattern:

```js
function toKebabCase(key) {
  return key.match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
    .map((word) => word.toLowerCase())
    .join('-');
}
console.log(toKebabCase('namespaceGray100Light'));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4i7BuR/1).

Note that your regex has two occurrences of `[0-9]*`:

- `(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)` - here, `[0-9]*` is redundant since it can match zero chars, an empty string, and is at the end of the lookahead alternative
- `[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*` - here, the `[0-9]*` consumes the digits after a letter word, but it is exactly where you need to add a `-` in between. The digits will get matched with the `[0-9]+` last alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `replace` for that case:

```js
function toKebabCase(key) {
  return key.match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
    .map((word) => word.toLowerCase())
    .join('-')
    .replace(/([^\d])(\d)/g, "$1-$2");
}

console.log(toKebabCase('namespaceGray100Light'));
```

No need to make an already complex regex more complicated.